# Select an sql field from html field and show it in another page

Tags: php, html

I have displayed sql table in html table, made a hyperlink near all fields, when i click it the whole field details should be shows in other page(ie; i show only 2 fields of sql in the table and want to show rest in another page).

admin.php

```
  <?php
    $con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("main",$con);
echo"<form action=\"post\" class=\"form-horizontal\" role=\"form\">";
echo "<table width='700' height='150' onclick='myFun(event)'>";
echo"   <tr>
        <td width='100' align='center'></td>
        <td width='100' align='center'><b><u>NAME</u></b></td>
        <td width='100' align='left'><b><u>E-MAIL</u></b></td>
    </tr>
    ";
 $result=mysql_query("select NAME,EMAIL from admin order by AID");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='center'><a href='viewadmin.php?name=".$row['NAME']."'>Select</a></td>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='center'>".$row['NAME']."</td>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='left'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
        }
echo"</table>";


echo"</form> ";
 ?>
```

viewadmin.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT NAME,DOB,MOB,EMAIL, FROM admin WHERE NAME = $name");
if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
 else {
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
}

echo" <form class=\"form-horizontal\" role=\"form\">
<table width='400'>
    <tr>
        <td  align='left'>Name</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['NAME']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>E-mail</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td align='left'>D.O.B</td>
        <td  align='left'>".$row['DOB']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>Mobile</td>
        <td align='left'>".$row['MOBILE']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>Photo</td>
        <td ><img src='uploads/grumpy.jpg' height='200' width='200'></td>
    </tr>
</table>";
echo"</form> ";
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Pass a unique property through the url. `<a href='viewadmin.php?name=".$row['NAME']."'>` and in your other page access that parameter through `$_GET['name']`. You can then create a MySQL query that uses `WHERE` to get the single row that you need.

Comment: if there are 5 fields in the table, how can i select a particular field and show it in another page?

Comment: You have to make a new database connection and query in the other page.

Comment: can you help me how to do it?

Comment: i have changed my code, edited my question with new code

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM admin WHERE NAME = Athul M K' at line 1
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 215      there are errors on a couple of statements like this <td align='left'>".$row['NAME']."</td>

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question. That isn't how the Q&A format of this site works. Either accept the answer below which provided you with a solution or post your own answer containing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:
admin.php

```
$result=mysql_query("select NAME,EMAIL from admin order by AID");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='center'><a href='viewadmin.php?name=".$row['NAME']."'>Select</a></td>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='center'>".$row['NAME']."</td>";
    echo"<td width='100' align='left'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

and in viewadmin.php

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name = $name");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "  <form class=\"form-horizontal\" role=\"form\">
        <table width='400'>
        <tr>
            <td  align='left'>".$row['NAME']."</td>
            <td align='left'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='left'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>
            <td align='left'>...";
```

Comment: I get this error :  mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 4

Comment: Do not access Superglobal $_GET Array Directly, an line 4 code is $row=mysql_fetch_row($results);

Comment: line 2 error :  Undefined index: name in :  $name = $_GET['name'];

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM admin WHERE NAME = Maneesh' at line 1
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 215

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 219

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 224

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainpro\viewadmin.php on line 228

Answer (score 0):

first rename the html page by php page, then you can pass the primary key or any key of the row from first page to admin page with the help of GET.
for eg:
first.php
     `<?php
    $result=mysql_query("select ID,NAME,EMAIL from admin order by AID");          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     ?><a hre='admin.php?id="$id=<?php $row[0] ?>"'></a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>`

and in the admin.php page 
you can access the value like

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

stop using MySQL and use MySQLi, this code should work

```
<?php
$db_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($db_connect)) {
    die('Some error occurred during connection to the database');
}
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,$_REQUEST['name']);
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_connect, 'SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name = ?')){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0){ 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<form class=\"form-horizontal\" role=\"form\">
        <table width='400'>
        <tr>
            <td  align='left'>".$row['NAME']."</td>
            <td align='left'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='left'>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>
            <td align='left'>..."
    }
    else{
        echo 'not found';
    }
}
else{
trigger_error('error:' . mysqli_errno($db_connect) . mysqli_error($db_connect));
    }
?>
```